# RecyclerView lazy loading TextView content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, lazy-loading

I am filling a `RecyclerView` with up to several thousand entries from a `sqlite database`, loaded through an `AsyncTaskLoader`. The list needs to be filterable, so I am required to load all entries at once. Some of the `TextViews` in the RecyclerView's ViewHolders contain results of further DB queries (based on the initial result) or other types of computations.

Expanding the initial query to include JOINs (which at least would make the secondary queries obsolete) really slows down loading. However doing the queries/computations inside the onBind method of the RecyclerView, makes flinging much less fluent, than without them.

Is there a way to do lazy load the content for these computed `TextViews`? I have searched for examples, but libraries like "Picasso" and "Glide" only allow loading images...

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter

Comment: @pskink: Thanks, but this adapter doesn't really suit my needs...

Comment: simply use JOINS, and no, for filtering you dont need  to load all entries at once, just override `runQueryOnBackgroundThread` or setup its `FilterQueryProvider`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a `Singleton` class  using an `ExecutorService` to do my loading/calculations in seperate threads and then having the `Handler` update my `ViewHolder`. Don't know, if this is the best way to do it, but so far it's working without any issues.

```
private static class LazyLoadManager {
    private static LazyLoadManager INSTANCE;
    private final ExecutorService pool;
    private Map<ViewHolder, String> viewHolders = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ViewHolder, String>());
    private Context context;

    private LazyLoadManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    public static LazyLoadManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new LazyLoadManager(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private void loadData(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final Model myModel) {

        // Put ViewHolder and respective tag into Map
        viewHolders.put(viewHolder, myModel.getTag());

        final Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

                // Get result object
                Model myResultModel = (Model) msg.obj;

                // Result was initialized
                if (myResultModel != null) {

                    // Get ViewHolder tag from map
                    String tag = viewHolders.get(viewHolder);

                    // Set ViewHolder content, if saved tag matches tag of this ViewHolder
                    if (tag != null && tag.equals(viewHolder.getTag())) {
                        viewHolder.viewA.setText(myResultModel.getThis());
                        viewHolder.viewB.setText(myResultModel.getThat());
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        pool.submit(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Model myResultModel = null;

                            if (myModel != null) {

                                // do required calculations and secondary queries based on myModel

                                myResultModel.setThis(result1);
                                myResultModel.setThat(result2);
                            }

                            Message message = Message.obtain();
                            message.obj = myResultModel;

                            handler.sendMessage(message);
                        }
                    }

        );
    }
```

In the `onBindViewHolder` method of my `RecyclerView` I then call my LazyLoadManager like this

```
LazyLoadManager.getInstance(context).loadData(viewHolder, myModel);
```